# Boto3: Is it possible to parallelize paginator of list_objects_v2 API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a s3 bucket called `my-bucket` and I have some files stored in the following structure:

```
my-bucket
        |----- subfolder_1 ----- uniqueId_1 
                   |                 |---- timestamp1.txt
                   |                 |---- timestamp2.txt
                   |                 |---- timestamp3.txt
                   |                 |---- ...
                   |
                   | ----------- uniqueId_2 
                                     |---- timestamp1.txt
                                     |---- timestamp2.txt
                                     |---- timestamp3.txt
                                     |---- ...
```

My goal is to get all unique "uniqueIds" and I don't care about the timestamp. However the following code took me about 5 minutes to get all uniqueIds under one "subfolder_1".

```
import time
import boto3

paginator = boto3.client("s3").get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket="my-bucket", Prefix="subfolder_1/")
    
uniqueKeys = set()
for page in pages:
for obj in page['Contents']:
    uniqueKeys.add(obj['Key'].split("/")[-2])

print(len(uniqueKeys))
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to use multithreading to replace or inside the `for` loop to accelerate this process?

Meanwhile I noticed if I use aws command line `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/subfolder_1/ | wc -l` it only takes 1 minute to finish, so an equivalent implementation using `boto3` would help me as well.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a list of the 'subdirectories' under `subfolder_1`, you could use:

```
boto3.client('s3').list_objects_v2(Bucket='foo',Prefix='subfolder_1/',Delimiter='/')
```

By specifying the `Delimiter`, S3 will also return a list of `CommonPrefixes`, which are effectively the name of the 'subdirectories' within that prefix.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this code but it didn't return what I want. The following is what I got:
`'CommonPrefixes': [{'Prefix': 'subfolder_1/'}]`

Comment: Oops, please add a slash at the end of the `Prefix` (`Prefix='subfolder_1/'`). I have corrected it above.

Comment: This approach only gave me 1000 results, however I have 10k+ "uniqueId_x" under the same subfolder

Comment: You can try it with pagination. I know that pagination works with listing objects, but I haven't tried it with retrieving `CommonPrefixes`. You can use your existing pagination code and just add `Delimiter='/'`. Let us know if it works!